# Does GCM support notifications over SMS

Tags: google-cloud-messaging

I'm working on a project that respond  to users by sending SMS for their request.
 Right now I use telerivet for forwarding the SMS to my back end.
I want to know whether I can use GCM to send SMS notification.

Comment: No GCM won't provide SMS notification

Comment: Is there any similar service that doesn't have messaging quota... I mean support for any long contents

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to what @Nilesh already said, you can actually check if a certain app would provide SMS services. Simply look into the uses-permissions in its manifest.

As you can see in the required components of the [GCM manifest](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client), it does not require `SEND_SMS` or `RECEIVE_SMS` permissions, which you would have needed to support sending or receiving SMS, respectively.